Does channel length modulation take effect in triode region of MOSFET?
AFAIK, the channel length modulation (CLM) effect only occurs in the saturation region due to the shrinking of the channel \$(*)\$. So, in ideality (\$\lambda=0\$), the \$I_D-V_{DS}\$ characteristic of an NMOS will be the blue dash line in the plot below.
If \$\lambda>0\$, the phenomenon will occur, and the formula for \$I_D\$ saturation region is
\$\frac{1}{2}\mu_nC_{ox}(V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2(1+\lambda V_{DS})\$. When I simulated the circuit below in LTspice, the characteristic was like the green dot line in the plot.

But if CLM only takes effect in saturation region and only appears in the saturation \$I_D\$ equation, why was there a big gap between the ideal \$V_{DS}\$ and the simulated \$V_{DS}\$ in triode region right before the triode edge (\$V_{DS}=V_{GS}-V_{TH}\$)? When I measured the \$I_D\$ in the triode region, I found that \$I_D\$ was calculated by
$$I_D=\frac{1}{2}\mu_nC_{ox}\left(2(V_{GS}-V_{TH})-V_{DS}^2\right)(1+\lambda V_{DS})$$
If the statement \$(*)\$ holds true, isn't it more precise to have the characteristic like the red solid line? How does the MOSFET behave in reality?
Any help would be appreciated.


I can confirm that the green line is what happens in reality, from having run countless SiC MOSFETs (which tend to have very short channel length and thus very strong channel-length modulation) through a semiconductor parameter analyzer.
In reality, there is no sharp transition from triode mode to saturation mode; the existence of these as distinct, separate things is a useful model, but still only a model, an approximation of what happens in reality.
Even in linear mode, the length of the channel affects performance (the channel being typically the highest-resistivity part of a MOSFET), and the length of the channel is still modulated by the drain to source voltage.

That means, (1) the channel length modulation shouldn't just stick with the pinch-off point, it is always modulated by the V_DS voltage but just how much; and (2), the multiplication with 1+lambda*V_DS is just the approximation of LTspice to make the curve smooth. Am I correct?

@Becker The existence of a pinchoff point at all is a bit of an oversimplification, as I understand it.

Some of the FET SPICE models (I forget the level number) explicitly include a parameter for channel length modulation AND are designed to smoothly transition between saturation and triode regions. OP can look up the equations to see how this is done.
In reality "saturation" and "triode" equations approximately describe the behavior in particular regions. There are no sharp transitions in real physical transistors or in numerical models of the device physics.
(addition) The Level 1 model (Schichman-Hodges) includes channel length modulation and uses the channel length modulation parameter below saturation. Physically this makes no sense but guarantees continuity at the saturation point.
